# Why there is a testing team?

Tags: testing, development-process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why to let / not let developers test their own work](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77146/why-to-let-not-let-developers-test-their-own-work)

Developers develop the code and software. Ya that means they know very well of what they have done. But why there is always a separate department in IT companies called as Testing department? (Mainly for testing developers outcome)

Why a developer is not doing **Testing** his or her own code? Is it Testing department knows very well about developers code, if so how come?

Thanks in advance.